# "Please add a @NgModule annotation" Error on Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, single-page-application, angular-module

I have made a custom angular2(5.0.x) module that looks like this :

```
import { GuageService } from './services/guage.service';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { GuageComponent } from './guage/guage.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [GuageComponent],

  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],

  providers : [GuageService],
  exports : [GuageComponent]
})
export class GuageModule {}
```

I use it in my app modules like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { DxButtonModule, DxCircularGaugeModule } from 'devextreme-angular';
import { GuageModule } from '@kronsbi/bi-module-template';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

        @NgModule({
          declarations: [
            AppComponent
          ],
          imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            DxButtonModule,
            DxCircularGaugeModule,
            HttpClientModule,
            GuageModule
          ],
          bootstrap: [AppComponent]
        })
        export class AppModule { }
```

When I try to start my app I get the following error.

> Unexpected value 'GuageModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

#### UPDATE

tsconfig for the main app:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

ts config for the GuageModule package:
{

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "declaration": true,
    "stripInternal": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "paths": {
      "@angular/core": ["node_modules/@angular/core"],
      "rxjs/*": ["node_modules/rxjs/*"]
    },
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2017", 
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "index.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictMetadataEmit": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: Added the tsconfigs

Comment: I had the exact same issue with this module, there is a pull request which fixes it, it can be found here - https://github.com/glaucoma-australia/ng-gauge - see the commits here - https://github.com/subarroca/ng-gauge/pull/11/commits

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are using Angular 5.0 you need to add `"annotationsAs": "decorators"` to the `"angularCompilerOptions"` for your package.
Angular 5 introduced new optimizations and by default the decorators are removed on compile because they are not needed at runtime. This does not work for packages as you already discovered. You can read about this in the Angular 5 announcement blog the "Build Optimizer" paragraph mentions this. [Version 5.0.0 of Angular Now Available](https://blog.angular.io/version-5-0-0-of-angular-now-available-37e414935ced)

I use this settings in my angular packages:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
      "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
      "skipMetadataEmit": false,
      "strictMetadataEmit": true,
      "annotationsAs": "decorators"
   }
```

Comment: Has something changed with Ivy? with "enableIvy: true" I see the decorator in the compiled code like ```ɵsetClassMetadata(MyLibModule, [{ type: NgModule,...``` but it still throws this error. With "enableIvy: false" the generated code is ```MyLibModule=__decorate$2([NgModule...``` and it works

Comment: Yes with Ivy the whole Angular compiler has changed as you see you get completely different code. This is an old post. I would suggest you try to update your project from a version before Ivy to Angular 9 which uses it as default using ng update following the [Angular update guide](https://update.angular.io/).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. With angular 5+ and angular cli 1.5 it says that your code is not compatible and also your library is scoped package. I have managed to fix it with adding

```
 export * from './your-path'
```

In all my files (exporting everything from my library).

As i understood its you import as 3 party library You can try to run the application with

```
 ng serve --preserve-symlinks
```

also add  flatModuleId in src/tsconfig.es5.json accordingly:

```
"flatModuleId": "@scope/library-name"
```

Link to github [here](https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library#how-can-i-use-a-scoped-package-name)

There is issue on [github](https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library/issues/170) for more information

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely an issue with the way your npm package is being created. In your package.json for your `GuageModule` are you defining a main? This should point to the entry point to your npm package. Here is an example of mine.

```
"main": "./dist/module.js",
```

Then if you want typings from GuageModule in your main app you'll need to go to your `tsconfig.json` and under `compilerOptions` set `declaration` to be true to generate the typings files.

```
"compilerOptions": {
  ...
  "declaration": true
  ...
},
```

Then finally in your `package.json` you will need to point to the entry point for your typings file.

```
"types": "./src/app/layout.module.d.ts"
```

Now you should be able to import your module and have typings on the module that you imported. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Please add  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true in the compilerOptions of tsconfig.json of your gauge module

Comment: Unless you have a very advanced, deliberate setup to recompile it from source, the dependency is already built and its tsconfig has no bearing on any of this.

Comment: I guess you miss somewhere. He is creating his own custom module (viz. Gaugle Module). So compilation is required for it to be used.