# ng4-Tag-Input Error: nexpected value 'TagInputModule' imported by the module 'CVModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having a message error in the console of Chrome, I am trying to see what is that an error but I don't get the solution.

I an working with Angular 5. And typescript.

I add all information I can think you can help to get my solution.

The template I am using in code of tag input is:

The module is:

```
import {TagInputModule} from 'ng4-tag-input';
import { TagComponent } from 'ng4-tag-input/dist/modules/ng4-tag-input.module';

// Import the library

const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  data: {
    title: 'Curriculum Vitae',
    urls: [{ title: 'Detall', url: '/cv' }, { title: 'CV' }]
  },
  component: CVComponent
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,    
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    TagInputModule
  ], 
  declarations: [   
    CVComponent,
    ClientComponent,
    CapcaleraComponent,
    EducacioComponent,
    ExperienciaLaboralComponent,
    RegladaComponent,
    NoRegladaComponent, 
    IdiomesComponent,
    EducacioComponent,
    ConeixementsComponent
  ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class CVModule { }
```

The component is:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-experiencialaboral',
  templateUrl: './experiencialaboral.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./experiencialaboral.component.scss'],  
  providers: [DataService],
})
export class ExperienciaLaboralComponent implements OnInit {
  public experiencialaboral: ExperienciaLaboral[] = new Array<ExperienciaLaboral>();
  public clase_experiencialaboral_titol:string[] = new Array<string>();
  public clase_experiencialaboral_panell:string[] = new Array<string>();
  public tags:any[] = [];
  public literal: ExperienciaLaboral = new ExperienciaLaboral(); 
  public cultura: string;
  public itemsAsObjects = [{value: 0, display: 'Angular'}, {value: 1, display: 'React'}];

  public Panel_ClickEvent_Titol(index): void {
    if (this.clase_experiencialaboral_titol[index].indexOf("noactiu_experiencialaboral_" + index) >= 0) {
      this.clase_experiencialaboral_titol[index] = "actiu_experiencialaboral_" + index;
      this.clase_experiencialaboral_panell[index] = "tancar_experiencialaboral_" + index;
    } 
    else {
      this.clase_experiencialaboral_titol[index] = "noactiu_experiencialaboral_" + index;
      this.clase_experiencialaboral_panell[index] = "obrir_experiencialaboral_" + index;
    }
  }


  constructor(public data: DataService, globals: Globals)
  {
    var that = this;
    this.cultura = globals.cultura;

    data.cargarDades(new ExperienciaLaboral()).then (
        res => { // Success
          debugger;

          for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++)  {                            
            let obj = res[i];

            obj["newMesFinal"] = new Date(obj["MesFinal"]);
          }

          var items = Enumerable.asEnumerable<ExperienciaLaboral>(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res))).OrderByDescending(x => x["newMesFinal"]).ToArray();

          for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)  {                            
            let obj = items[i];

            //obj.EsClient = obj.EsClient;
            //obj.mesinicial = new Date(obj.mesinicial);
            //obj.mesfinal = new Date(obj.mesfinal);

            if (obj.Tecnologies) {
              obj.Tags = [];
              obj.Tecnologies.split(',').forEach(
                function (item) {
                  obj.Tags.push({text: item});
                }
              );
            }

            this.experiencialaboral.push(obj);
          }

          this.experiencialaboral.forEach(function (obj, index)  {
            that.clase_experiencialaboral_titol.push("noactiu_experiencialaboral_" + index);
            that.clase_experiencialaboral_panell.push("obrir_experiencialaboral_" + index);
          });

        }
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

The Error is whem I am executing ng serve:

**WARNING in ./node_modules/ng4-tag-input/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js 5662:15-36
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression**

**WARNING in ./node_modules/ng4-tag-input/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js 5678:15-102
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression**

And in Chrome console:

[image]

And my package json is:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^7.2.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "^5.1.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.0.0",
    "ang-jsoneditor": "^1.7.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "jsoneditor": "^5.27.0",
    "linq-es2015": "^2.4.34",
    "ng4-tag-input": "^1.0.5",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^7.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.12.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  }
}
```

My angular.json is:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "frontend": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/frontend",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "frontend:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "frontend:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "frontend:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "frontend-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "frontend:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "frontend:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "frontend"
}
```

Finally tsconfig.json is:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

I wrote the code of a possible solution but I get this error:

[image]

And I am getting the warnings yet:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution,

Seems was the order of your package.json. I recovored a backup in my cloud and seems after install with: **npm install** is working.

Maybe it is something of the version. **ng4-tag-input** is crashing for any reason. I replaced with **ngx-tags-input**.

Here is my new package.json:

```
{
  "name": "admin-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^7.2.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^11.1.2",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.22.1",
    "angular-linq": "^1.0.6",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.1",
    "chartist": "^0.11.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "d3-request": "^1.0.6",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
    "linq-es2015": "^2.4.32",
    "ng-chartist": "^1.1.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-dragula": "^1.5.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-smart-table": "^1.2.2",
    "ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
    "ngx-papaparse": "^2.1.0",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-quill": "^2.0.4",
    "ngx-responsive-stack-table": "^1.0.2",
    "ngx-tags-input": "^1.1.1",
    "pace-js": "^1.0.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.5",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.12.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/chartist": "^0.9.37",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.5",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.111",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't reproduce the issue. A thing, I noticed is that you aren't exporting anything that other modules, importing CVModule might need. If CVModule is not your root module( I am almost sure it isn't) you could try this. Hope it helps you continue with your project. You could also try to export the complete TagInputModule in case you are using any dependent components other than TagComponent in the modules that are dependend on CVModule (or importing it in other words) :

```
import {TagInputModule} from 'ng4-tag-input';
import { TagComponent } from 'ng4-tag-input/dist/modules/ng4-tag-input.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // All imports ...
  ], 
  declarations: [   
   // All declarations ...
  ],
  schemas: [
   // All schemas 
] , 
  exports : [RouterModule , TagComponent] 
})
export class CVModule { }
```

Comment: I exported the component and I couldnt resolve it. I am thinking to build another module in a level of experienciaprofesional which is where I am using, bnut i think it wont works anyway sure

Comment: Could you please try then the solution proposed in the following StackOverflow discussion : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47331202/please-add-a-ngmodule-annotation-error-on-angular2/47445313

Comment: I added the new information in the same question, at the end. I will give you a link of ng4-tag-input which tells you https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng4-tag-input, anyway I will test your new orupose of the link

Comment: I tested all options and the same error, not working yet